# search arraylist by id-java

Tags: java, arraylist

The following program asks to give the number of the players and their names. I want to put the names in a arraylist and return them by their id.

```
private static ArrayList<Player>Playerlist=new ArrayList<Player>();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s;


   {
        System.out.printf("number of players(2 -4)? ");

    int p = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.nextLine();
    for(int i=0;p>4 || p<2;i++)
     {

         System.out.printf("only 2-4 players.\n");
         System.out.printf("number of players(2 -4)?");
         p = scanner.nextInt();
         scanner.nextLine();

     }
   Player pl=new Player();
   int m=1;
    for(int k=1;k<=p;k++)
     {


         System.out.printf("give the name of the player %d: ",k);
         s= scanner.nextLine();
         pl.setName(s,m);
         System.out.printf(pl.getName());
         Playerlist.add(pl);
       m++;
      }
  public class Player {

  private String name;
  private int id;

  public Player () {
   }

  Player(String val,int k) {
    this.name = val;
    this.id=k;}
  /**
   * getName
  *
  */
public String getName () {
    return name;
}

/**
 * setName

 */
public void setName (String val,int k) {
    this.name = val;
    this.id=k;
}
public void displayStudentDetails(){
    System.out.println("ID is "+id);
    System.out.println("Name is "+name)};
```

i dont know how to do the search by id...i have tried many things but they didnt work....

Comment: I don't understand the "do the search by id". You add your Player's objects in an ArrayList so you are able to get the id and the name of each player, just by going through the array list.
Could you give an example about what you want exaclty?

Comment: Based on how you are assigning ids, it looks like they start at 1 for the first player, and increase by 1 (so player 2 has id 2).  If this is always going to be the case, then to get the player for an "id" you would just do Playerlist.get(id - 1);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better solution would be to use a `HashMap<Integer, String>`, with the id being the key and the name being the value. Then you can search easily:

```
HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
map.put(1, "Robert");
map.put(2, "Jeff");
```

Then to search:

```
String name = map.get(1); // will return "Robert"
```

**Edit**: Ok, if you need more data than just name, like score, you will need to create a data type. Like:

```
public class Player {
    private String name;
    private int score;
    // etc.

    public Player(String name, int score) {
        this.name = name;
        this.score = score;
    }
}
```

And then you can add objects of this type to the map like:

```
map.put(1, new Player("Robert", 10));
```

Comment: @des: Don't forget to select accept answer if it solved your problem. :)

Comment: do you know if it is possible to add some more things to my HashMap...for example i want to add the score to esch player and will be like this-->1,Robert,300  or 2,Jeff,450 an i If i search by the id it wii return the name and the score...

Comment: thanks a lot for your response...i created the new class Player as you said and when i write this in main "map.put(1, new Player("Robert", 10));" i get this message "cannot find symbol:method put(int,game.Player)"...

Comment: @des, you have to change the map declaration to HashMap<Integer, Player>.

Comment: yes i find it out!and one more question(the last i promise!) i do the search "Player map1 = map.get(2); 
        System.out.print(map1); "in oreder to return the name and the score of the player with id=2 and it returns this game.Player@60aeb03...do you know why?

Comment: @des, you need to put methods to get the values from the Player class like public String getName() { return name; } and then you can do print(map1.getName()); and the same for score.

Comment: Thanks sooo much!!You are an expert in JAVA!!:)))

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the fact that you should have classes in different files without global variables at this time...

```
/**
 * Searches the PlayerList Arraylist for a Player having the ID of the parameter passed
 */
public Player searchByID(int id) {
  //Do some sort of check on id to ensure its valid?
  for (int i = 0; i < PlayerList.size(); i++) {
    if (PlayerList.get(i).getID() == id) {
      return PlayerList.get(i);
    }
  }

  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList is probably the wrong data structure.  If you want to retrieve the elements in id order, you want a HashMap if the ids are all regular in the sense that you can be sure of things like "ids are 1 to 10 and there are no unused ids".  If the id set is sparse, you'll want a to use TreeMap or TreeSet depending on your other use cases.

Answer (score 0):

If the situation where you need to get the player by ID is based exactly on how your code is adding players, then you can just do:

```
public Player getPlayerById(int id)
{
  return PlayerList.get(id - 1);
}
```

Since you are assigning player ids linearly starting at 1 for the first player.  If you are modifying or otherwise changing the order of players and ids then you will need to use one of the other suggestions (but if you are not doing that then this is the most optimized solution).

Note: The code above will throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException if the id does not exist in the player list, do you may want to modify the code depending on how you want to handle that.